# How do I split a string into an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, delimiter

I am trying to split each line of a String read by my `FileReader` and `BufferedReader`. I am getting a syntax error at `String [] x = Login.Split("");`

What method can I use to split the `String`? I will be adding a method to see if the string matches made by another input, but for now I need to figure out how to split a string and still have each line Separate.
 (I am trying to find another way to make a login since I have java 8 and cannot use sql and the  ucanaccess didn't seem to help either ) I also attempted to use a delimiter, but couldn't find a good applicable example.

```
private void SubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {      
    try {
        FileReader FR = new FileReader("Login.txt");
        BufferedReader Login = new BufferedReader(FR);
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

        String str;
        String [] x = Login.Split("");
        while ((str = Login.readLine()) !=null ) { 
            sb.append(str);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        Login.close();
        FR.close();

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        Scanner read = new Scanner(Login);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exception 2, " );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to split?  The `Login.readLine` will read single lines from your input.  These single lines are assigned to `str`.  Do you want to split `str` more?

Comment: aw yes I think your pointing me in the right direction. I need to Split each line, and then scan the array from each line to see if it matches the user name and password.

Comment: You're calling `Split` on the buffered reader. `Split` is a method of [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), not `BufferedReader`.

Comment: The `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` are both irrelevant here. You already have the `String:` how you got it is immaterial. Try focussing on the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not clear on what you want?

A : You want to put single seperate lines from your reader into an aray? Well as far as I know that the readline() method reads a line of text already.

or

B You want to split the words in the line in that case you can try to use this : String[] x = Login.trim().split("//s"); //The RegEx will account for more than one space between words and the trim() will cut of spaces at the start and end of the line if any.

BUT I can see that you are not reading a line into your reader before trying to split the words in the array. So it is trying to split something that doesn't have any data in it.

Note I'm just starting in Java but I hope this helps.

Comment: you hit it right on the head. I wasn't focusing on the right part of the problem. For some reason I thought I needed to compare two words on the same line, and with that thought the best way to do that was to make an array, and compare it to the input from the user.   When in reality the easier solution is to string the two inputs together and compare them to the line of the file.  ( now to figure out how to make that all happen. I think I almost have it. )

Comment: I'm glad i could be of help :)

Comment: trim() will not take the white-space off the individual parts as they get put into the x array.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your new comment

```
String str;
while ((str = Login.readLine()) !=null ) { 

    String [] x = str.Split(" ");

    // ?? new method to scan string array
    scanThis (x);
    sb.append(str);
    sb.append("\n");
```

}

```
void scanThis (String arr[]) 
{
  for (int x = ; x < arr.length; x++) {
  {
      if (arr[x].equals ("login")) {
          System.out.println ("Hurray");
          break;
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: I am trying to test your code, but Its giving my problems because its inside an awaiting action class. ( I think thats the problem plus several others. )  I am not experienced enough to know how to do what I need to.

Comment: You don't need the second method. Just call `arr.contains("login")`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting a syntax error at `String [] x = Login.Split("");`

No you aren't, you are getting a compiler error reading something like 'no such method'. That's not a syntax error.

`Login` (stupid name) is a `BufferedReader`, and `BufferedReader` doesn't have a `Split()` method. `String` on the other hand *does* have a `split()` method (note the case). Presumably that is what you're looking for.

But splitting on an empty string isn't going to accomplish anything useful.

Comment: your right. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. In fact I feel so silly I want to remove my entire post. I am realizing that I can just compare the entire line so what my user will input and add the two inputs together, then compare the whole line.